# R Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I'm trying to make a dashboard in Shiny using 2 apps. 
I see one of the apps and the second is an empty box.

Getting the error:

> Warning: attributes are not identical across measure variables; they
>   will be dropped extract_numeric() is deprecated: please use
>   readr::parse_numeric() instead

```
liibrary(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyr)
library(leaflet)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)

#APP 1 THE WORLD MAP
P <- read.csv("Lebara_weeks_rev4.csv")

# do munging that won't change based on input here
P2 <- gather(P, week, value, Week.1:Week.29)    # gather to long form
P2$value <- extract_numeric(P2$value)    # convert to numeric

#APP 2 THE HISTOGRAM OF PAYMENTS

pays <- read.csv("adeyn.csv")
PayAuths <- c("Date", "Total.Transactions", "Abandoned","Completed", "Authorised", "Redirected", "Redirected.Returned")
newPays <- pays[PayAuths]
payMelted <- melt(newPays, id=c("Date"))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(selectInput("weekView", "Week's Revenue:",
                      c("1" = "Week.1",
                        "2" = "Week.2",
                        "3" = "Week.3",
                        "4" = "Week.4",
                        "5" = "Week.5",
                        "6" = "Week.6",
                        "7" = "Week.7",
                        "8" = "Week.8",
                        "9" = "Week.9",
                        "10" = "Week.10",
                        "11" = "Week.11",
                        "12" = "Week.12",
                        "13" = "Week.13",
                        "14" = "Week.14",
                        "15" = "Week.15",
                        "16" = "Week.16",
                        "17" = "Week.17",
                        "18" = "Week.18",
                        "19" = "Week.19",
                        "20" = "Week.20",
                        "21" = "Week.21",
                        "22" = "Week.22",
                        "23" = "Week.23",
                        "24" = "Week.24",
                        "25" = "Week.25",
                        "26" = "Week.26",
                        "27" = "Week.27",
                        "28" = "Week.28",
                        "29" = "Week.29")
      )
      )),



      box(
        leafletOutput("mymap")
      ),


    box(
      renderPlot("mymap2")
    )

    )
  )


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    # do munging dependent on input here
    P3 <- P2[P2$week == input$weekView, ]    # subset based on input

    leaflet(data = P3) %>%
      addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, 
                       popup = ~format(value, big.mark = ','),    # reinsert commas
                       radius = ~value/40000,
                       stroke = FALSE, 


                       fillOpacity = 0.5)
  })


  output$mymap2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = payMelted, aes(Date, value, fill=variable))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))


  })  


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any obvious issues?  I can supply the two csv files too.

Comment: Try to use `parse_numeric` from `readr` instead of deprecated `extract_numeric`: `P2$value <- readr::parse_numeric(P2$value)`. You can also simplify choices: `setNames(paste0("Week.", 1:29), as.character(1:29))`

Comment: Thanks. The main issue I have is the histogram, mymap2, is not rendering. The one with weeks, mymap, appears.

Comment: It is because you have `renderPlot("mymap2")` instead of `plotOutput("mymap2")` in UI script

Comment: Thanks.  That was silly.